# Extract text blocks between tags separated by <br> without a tag title

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a web page that has a series of  tags with a specific class within the page. The  tags I'm interested in look like this:

```
<span class="my-span-class">
  "Text of interest before break"
  <br>
  "Text of interest after break"    
</span>
```

These elements have no title and are just  tags filled with text and are each broken up only by 1 
 tag. I want my end result to have "Text of interest before break" be in a separate list from "Text of interest after break" like this:

```
my_list_1 [Text of interest before break #1, Text of interest before break #2, Text of interest before break #3, etc...]

my_list _2 [Text of interest after break #1, Text of interest after break #2, Text of interest after break #3, etc....]
```

However, I'm struggling to get from what's below to having two separate lists. This currently outputs the two string together like so: "Text of interest before breakText of interest after break"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

f = urllib.request.urlopen("html.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

# get the tag type that looks like the element shown above
myText = soup.find_all("span", class_="my-span-clas")

results = []

for i in myText:
    results.append(i.text.strip())
```

I want to have a separate list initialized (i.e. results_2 = []) and have "Text of interest after break" be stored there and have the first results list be reserved only for the "Text of interest before break"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try htql:

```
import htql

page="""
<span class="my-span-class">
  Text of interest before break #1
  <br> 
  Text of interest after break #1
</span>
<span class="my-span-class">
  Text of interest before break #2
  <br> 
  Text of interest after break #2
</span>
"""

results1 = htql.query(page, "<span (class='my-span-class')>.<br>1:px &trim ")

results2 = htql.query(page, "<span (class='my-span-class')>.<br>1:fx &trim ")
```

It produces:

```
>>> results1
[('Text of interest before break #1',), ('Text of interest before break #2',)]
>>> results2
[('Text of interest after break #1',), ('Text of interest after break #2',)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group nodes before and after `<br>`.

I've gone ahead and made it a bit more robust by handling non-text elements before and after `<br>`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import itertools

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<span class="my-span-class">
  before break 1
  <span>before break 1.1</span>
  <br>
  after break 1
</span>

<span class="my-span-class">
  before break 2
  <br>
  after break 2
  <span>after break 2.1</span>
</span>

''', 'html.parser')


befores, afters = [], []
for it in soup.select('.my-span-class'):
    # this will give you three groups
    groups = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(it.children, lambda c: c.name != 'br')]
    # we just need items before br and after br
    before, after = [g for g in groups if g[0].name != 'br']
    
    befores.extend(before)
    afters.extend(after)
             
print(befores)
print(afters)
```

which prints:

```
['\n  before break 1\n  ', <span>before break 1.1</span>, '\n', '\n  before break 2\n  ']
['\n  after break 1\n', '\n  after break 2\n  ', <span>after break 2.1</span>, '\n']
```

This should be enough to demonstrate how you can partition children under an element.

The only thing left to do is to loop over `befores` and `afters` and clean up each item.

Comment: Thanks @abdusco for your answer. It looks like I'm getting a value error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` at this line: `before, after = [g for g in groups if g[0].name != 'br']`

Comment: It means there are some span's without br in them.

Comment: Or span's with nothing after or before br. Simply put: some spans can't be partitioned into two

Answer (score 1):

Based on your html you can use `contents` to get the values from the tag.

`contents[0]` will return first string

`contents[-1]` will return last string

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<span class="my-span-class">
  Text of interest before break
  <br>
  Text of interest after break   
</span>
<span class="my-span-class">
  Text of interest before break 1
  <br>
  Text of interest after break 1   
</span>
<span class="my-span-class">
  Text of interest before break 2
  <br>
  Text of interest after break 2    
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
Beforelist=[]
Afterlist=[]
for item in soup.find_all("span", class_="my-span-class"):
    Beforelist.append(item.contents[0].strip())
    Afterlist.append(item.contents[-1].strip())
    
print(Beforelist)
print(Afterlist)
```

**Output**:

```
['Text of interest before break', 'Text of interest before break 1', 'Text of interest before break 2']
['Text of interest after break', 'Text of interest after break 1', 'Text of interest after break 2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`.stripped_strings`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#strings-and-stripped-strings) in combination with `zip(*iterable)` to unpack them seperately.

```
myTexts = (tag.stripped_strings for tag in soup.find_all("span", class_="my-span-class"))
before, after = zip(*myTexts)

>>> before
('Text of interest before break', 'Text of interest before break 1', 'Text of interest before break 2')

>>> after
('Text of interest after break', 'Text of interest after break 1', 'Text of interest after break 2')
```